# VBScript related to AD

Tags: authentication, vbscript, active-directory

I have few AD related VBScripts and all r working fine but now i need to add few things into it, that is,when i double click on the vbscript to run it i want a prompt asking for user name and password and only if the entered credential exists in the company domain, it should execute else should throw an error.

Below i am posting a script which i got and which will serve half of the purpose but even this is throwing an error "Logon Failure:unknown username or bad password".

I am still a beginner and any help will help a lot to learn.

```
'On Error Resume Next
sUser = "userxyz"
sDN = "uid=" & sUser & ",cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com"
sRoot = "LDAP://ldapserver/cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com"

Dim oDS: Set oDS = GetObject("LDAP:")

Dim oAuth: Set oAuth = oDS.OpenDSObject(sRoot, sDN, "Password", &H200)

MsgBox "Login Successful"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uid=...,cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com` is not a valid distinguished name. You probably meant `cn=...,cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com`. Note that in this case `sUser` must be the common name of the user (attribute `cn`), not the username (attribute `sAMAccountName`). Replace the line

```
sDN = "uid=" & sUser & ",cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com"
```

with

```
sDN = "cn=" & sUser & ",cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com"
```

You can check the distinguished name and other attributes of AD objects via *Active Directory Users and Computers*. Click *View → Advanced Features*, open the properties the user object you want to inspect, and select the *Attribute Editor* tab.

---

If `sUser` is the username: you can use that for authentication as well, but you need to specify both username and domain, either as `CONTOSO\userxyz` or `userxyz@contoso.com`.

```
sUser = "userxyz@contoso.com"
sRoot = "LDAP://ldapserver/cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com"

Dim oDS: Set oDS = GetObject("LDAP:")

Dim oAuth: Set oAuth = oDS.OpenDSObject(sRoot, sUser, "Password", &H200)

MsgBox "Login Successful"
```